# Inserting data in same table but from multiple source. How to retain existing records in database?

Tags: c#, sql, insert, sql-insert

I am currently working on a data modelling project using c#. I have 2 files which insert records in the same table.

Both files insert data into the student table.

The student table contains the following fields

firstName, surName, contact, course, tutorName

Data is first run and all details are inserted on the above fields, however the second file is used to update certain values such as ContacNo,

I have the following insert string

```
 string insertStudent = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[Student] " +
                        "(firstName, surName, contact, course, tutor)"
                        +"VALUES(@fn, @sn, @contact, @course, @tutor)";
```

When running file A, the following is executed perfectly which inserts data into the table as required,

```
 queryStudent.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fn", firstName);
 queryStudent.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sn", surName);  
 queryStudent.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact", contact); 
 queryStudent.Parameters.AddWithValue("@course", course);
 queryStudent.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tutor", tutor);
```

The second file is used to update student data and when I run the below line of code for file B, I get a **"must declare the scalar variable"** error. I understand why I get this, as the tutor and course fields declared in the string are not present.

```
 queryStudent.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact", contact); 
 queryStudent.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fn", firstName); 
 queryStudent.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sn", surName);
```

How can I overcome this problem so that when the second instruction is run, only the 3 fields are inserted and the other fields in the table are retained?

Comment: You'll need an `update` statement for your 2nd file, not an `insert` statement.

Comment: Either you need to do an `update` as @sstan mentioned, or if you are trying to create new records, you will have to edit your `INSERT` string to only include the fields you want to insert into `"(contact, firstName,surname)"`